# C++ member function wrapper for interfacing with C APIs

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

Some C API interfaces use callbacks. Often these callbacks have a user-defined parameter of type `void *` which can be used as a class instance pointer in C++. Usually in order to call the member function you need to write a static class function which would cast the `void *` parameter to an instance pointer and call the member function. I wanted to write a wrapper that would instantiate a static function which takes `void *` as a parameter and the rest of arguments is exactly like in the member function passed to wrapper.

```
template<
    typename Result,
    typename Function,
    auto Func
>
struct instance_call_helper;

template<
    typename Result,
    typename Base,
    typename... Args,
    auto Func
>
struct instance_call_helper<
    Result,
    Result(Base::*)(Args...),
    Func
> {
    static Result call(void * ref, Args ... args) {
        Base * instance = reinterpret_cast<Base *>(ref);
        return (instance->*Func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

template <
    typename Base
> struct instance_type_helper;
template <
    typename Result, typename Base, typename... Args
>
struct instance_type_helper<Result(Base::*)(Args...)> {
    using result_t = Result;
};

template<auto Func>
#if __cpp_concepts >= 201507
requires std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(Func)>::value
#endif
class instance_call {
    using functor_t = decltype(Func);
    using type_helper = instance_type_helper<functor_t>;

public:
    using helper = instance_call_helper<
        typename type_helper::result_t,
        functor_t,
        Func
    >;
};
```

Intended usage:

```
class Bar {
private:
    int m_a1;

public:
    Bar(int a1):
        m_a1(a1) {}

    int baz(int a2) {
        return m_a1 + a2;
    }
};

int foo() {
    Bar b { 3 };
    // Pointer we are going to pass somewhere as a callback
    // f has signature int (*)(void*, int)
    auto * f = &instance_call<&Bar::baz>::helper::call;
    // Intended way of calling it — returns 5
    return f(&b, 2);
}
```

Comment: None of this is portable. Remember C is a different language. The only thing a C library understands are C things. The only thing C has is functions. This `instance_call<&Bar::baz>::helper::call` is a member function, as such C does not know how to call it. Now on a lot of platforms the calling convention for static member functions is the same as the calling convention for C functions; but there is no guarantee of this in any standard and thus UB.

Comment: When  you get into var args you are way of reservation. The only thing you can portably pass to a C library (from C++) is an `extern "C" <type> func(void*)`

Comment: Right. However, I plan to use this on a platform where the calling convention is the same. Apart from C, I also have C++ code where callbacks use `void *` for additional user data because `std::function` and `std::bind` can't be used due to space constraints.

Comment: These aren't varargs, it's template parameter packs.

Comment: One thing that needs careful handling when dealing with C/C++ interop are exceptions. You should either mark callback function as `noexcept` or convert exceptions into form suitable for particular C library.

Answer (score 1):

After using the code for a while I noticed the following changes could be used:

1. I don't need `instance_type_helper` class. Result type will be taken out of the function type. Thus, `instance_call_helper` turns into following:

   ```
   template<
       typename Function,
       Function F
   >
   struct instance_call_helper;

   template<
       typename Result,
       typename Base,
       typename... Args,
       Result(Base::* Func)(Args...)
   >
   struct instance_call_helper<
       Result(Base::*)(Args...),
       Func
   >
   ```
2. In order to use this code with GCC 6, one can check the value of `__cpp_deduction_guides` macro:

   ```
   #if __cpp_deduction_guides >= 201606
   template<
       auto F
   >
   #else
   template<
       typename Function,
       Function F
   >
   #endif
   ```
3. For use with C code (it's not portable, as noticed in the comments), some more advanced typechecking can be used for arguments, like `std::is_fundamental` or `std::is_pod`